# Matching a variable with an object inside a nested array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find a match inside this JSON array but I find it a bit complicated since it's a nested array of objects.

I'm not sure what I am doing entire wrong here:

The idea is that I have an array with a set of permissions and I want to return only the set of permissions that match the role:

```
var data = [{
    "visitor": {
        "static": ["page-one:visit", "home-page:visit", "login"]
    }
}, {
    "users": {
        "static": ["posts:list", "posts:create", "users:getSelf", "home-page:visit", "dashboard-page:visit"]
    }
}, {
    "admin": {
        "static": ["posts:list", "posts:create", "posts:edit", "posts:delete", "users:get", "users:getSelf", "home-page:visit", "dashboard-page:visit"]
    }
}]


var role = "admin"

for(var x=0;x <data.length;x++){

  if(role === data[x]){
    console.log("OLE, we got a match!" + data[x])
  }

}
```

For some reason I just can't find a match. I just wanna return the full object like:

```
"admin":{ 
        "static": ["posts:list", "posts:create", "posts:edit", "posts:delete", "users:get", "users:getSelf", "home-page:visit", "dashboard-page:visit"]
    }
```

[Here is a JS Bin Link.](https://jsbin.com/mamujipota/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.find` function like below:

`data.find(function(x){ return Object.keys(x).indexOf(role) > -1; });`

Given your role is the key of the object, you need to check if the object itself contains the role as a key, for this you'd use `Object.keys(<object>).indexOf(role)` where `indexOf` will return the value of `-1` if it's not found and `0+` if found.

```js
var data = [{"visitor":{"static":["page-one:visit","home-page:visit","login"]}},{"users":{"static":["posts:list","posts:create","users:getSelf","home-page:visit","dashboard-page:visit"]}},{"admin":{"static":["posts:list","posts:create","posts:edit","posts:delete","users:get","users:getSelf","home-page:visit","dashboard-page:visit"]}}]


var role = "admin"

var admins = data.find(function(x){ return Object.keys(x).indexOf(role) > -1; });

console.log(admins);
```

if you wanted to accommodate for an array of different roles, you can use the following, easy to follow example.

```js
var data = [{"visitor":{"static":["page-one:visit","home-page:visit","login"]}},{"users":{"static":["posts:list","posts:create","users:getSelf","home-page:visit","dashboard-page:visit"]}},{"admin":{"static":["posts:list","posts:create","posts:edit","posts:delete","users:get","users:getSelf","home-page:visit","dashboard-page:visit"]}}]


var role = ["admin", "visitor"];

var admins = role.map(function(role) { return getObjectsForRole(role); })
  
  
function getObjectsForRole(role)
{

 return data.find(function(x){ 
  return Object.keys(x).indexOf(role) > -1; 
  });

}

console.log(admins);
```

The above is pretty much the same as before, but we're mapping (`.map`) each role and calling a function which contains our call to the `.find` function.

Comment: Does the solution work if I have the variable `role` set to an array? Something like this `var role = ["admin", "visitor"]` ? Would I return both sets of permissions then ?

Comment: No. That wasn't your question why would I think outside the box to accommodate made up requirements? :)

Comment: I was just asking generally. Thank you for providing a solution and an explanation tho'. 

I was just being curious how it could work with two roles..

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard It's ok to ask questions, but put them in your main question rather than a comment. See my edit :)

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `find` to get all results and not just the first match. You can also use the `in` operator and an arrow function to make the code shorter: `const admins = data.filter(obj => role in obj);`

Comment: Thank you and yes, note taken. I did't format my question appropriately to accommodate all my cases.

Comment: @radulfr It only seems that the array has one of anyway, unless OP confirms that the array can hold multiple of the same role I personally think `find` is more beneficial. As for the second tip, yes, however I believe it's clearer to use `indexOf` to explain things on this site. Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it, it doesn't even make sense to have several results. Disregard that.